# How can I fix a 'Page not found' error when sending data from React to Laravel using URLs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I wanted to send data from react to laravel using URL.

React:

```
<button id="app" onClick={() => handleApproveClick(item.linkT, item.linkR, item.game_id, item.decx)}>Approve</button>
function handleApproveClick(linkT, linkR, gameId, decx) {
    const data = {
        linkT: linkT,
        linkR: linkR,
        gameId: gameId,
        decx: decx
    };
    window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/approve/${data.gameId}/${encodeURIComponent(data.linkR)}/${data.decx}/${encodeURIComponent(data.linkT)}`;
}
```

---

In the React side everything is working fine but in the link that goes to laravel I see page not found.

Laravel:

```
Route::get('/approve/{game_id}/{linkR}/{decx}/{linkt}', function($game_id, $decx, $linkt, $linkR) {
    dd($linkt.$linkR.$game_id.$decx);
});
```

I started to remove the variables to see where the problem is and I found it's the links that cause it.

If I use:

```
Route::get('/approve/{game_id}/{decx}
```

it works fine but when I add the links

```
get('/approve/{game_id}/{linkR}/{decx}/{linkt}
```

I see page not found.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the constructed URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/approve/${data.gameId}/${encodeURIComponent(data.linkR)}/${data.decx}/${encodeURIComponent(data.linkT}

Comment: @Q8root sure : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/approve/5/https%3A%2F%2Ffitgirl-repacks.site%2Fthe-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-anniversary-edition%2F/only%20the%20delux%20edition%20is%20availbe%20the%20GOY%20is%20not%20producet%20yet%20we%20will%20put%20it%20when%20it%20came%20:)/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.1377x.to%2Ftorrent%2F5162116%2FELDEN-RING-Deluxe-Edition-v1-02-DLC-Bonus-Content-MULTi14-FitGirl-Repack-Selective-Download-from-36-4-GB%2F"

Comment: The order of the route parameters `/approve/{game_id}/{linkR}/{decx}/{linkt}` and the function parameters `function($game_id,$decx,$linkt,$linkR)` are not in sync.

Comment: Your issue is that you are passing a route parameter to laravel (linkR and linkt) both are contain an URL encoded data and they contain a "/,%F..." , in order to figure out your issue, i need the result of console.log(linkT) and console.log(linkR) from your handleApproveClick() function

Comment: @linktoahref i made the right order but nothing changed same error

Comment: @linktoahref i did not say something about the order, can you provide the console.log(linkT) and console.log(linkR) from your handleApproveClick() function

Comment: sure thing console.log(linkT) :https://www.1377x.to/torrent/5162116/ELDEN-RING-Deluxe-Edition-v1-02-DLC-Bonus-Content-MULTi14-FitGirl-Repack-Selective-Download-from-36-4-GB/                                                                                                                        console.log(linkR) : https://fitgirl-repacks.site/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-anniversary-edition/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you pass `linkT` and `linkR` as query parameters.

```
<button id="app"
    onClick={() => handleApproveClick(item.linkT, item.linkR, item.game_id, item.decx)}
>Approve</button>

function handleApproveClick(linkT, linkR, gameId, decx) {
    const data = {
        gameId: gameId,
        decx: decx
    };

    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
        linkT: linkT,
        linkR: linkR
    });

    window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/approve/${data.gameId}/${data.decx}?${queryParams.toString()}`;
}
```

And modify the Route accordingly, so that the input could be retrieved from the [query string](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string):

```
Route::get('/approve/{game_id}/{decx}', function($game_id, $decx) {
    $linkR = request()->query('linkR');
    $linkT = request()->query('linkT');

    dd($linkT.$linkR.$game_id.$decx);
});
```

Make sure to clear the route cache using `php artisan route:cache` if there is route not found error.

Comment: i wrote your code but still same error 404|page not found